# Booting problems after update

Tags: boot, grub2, updates, live-usb, live-cd

Yesterday I updated my laptop (Lenovo ThinkPad T440p) to Ubuntu 14.04. Afterwards I restarted the laptop, but the operating system wouldn't start. I can''t get into the booting menu to choose Ubuntu (or Windows 7), I come directly to a black screen showing me

```
error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found. 
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue> _
```

After typing ls, I get the following output:

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos6) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,msdos1)
```

and after ls (hd0,msdos6) just "Filesystem is unknown." Using the other partitions give me the same result.

I tried to boot from a Ubuntu-Live-DVD and a Ubuntu-Live_USB, but it says

```
* Starting Recovery options if display manager fails to start   [fail]
* Stopping Recovery options if display manager fails to start   [OK]
[122.775345] SQUASHFS error: zlib decompression failed, data probably corrupt
[122.775371] SQUASHFS error: squashfs_read_data failed to read block 0x1eef27d9
...
```

so I can't even start the Live-Version. Strange.

One thing I tried: I installed Super Grub Disk onto a USB-drive and tried to Boot with it, but I always get the error Message

```
findf /etc/fstab
Error 15: File not found
```

Now I don't know further. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: I met similar issue in the past, I think your partition table entries got out of order. Take a look at my own answer in the end here http://askubuntu.com/questions/420778/i-need-step-by-step-guidence-to-recover-grub

Comment: I can't even load the LiveDVD, how can I execute those commands?

Comment: I don't know much about UEFI but you can try to disable it and boot  livedvd

Comment: I'm booting the livedvd. I get the ubuntu-logo and the 5 points, but then I'm always getting the error, I wrote about above.

Comment: your livedvd appears to be broken, try liveUSB.

Comment: Same result. I even downloaded the iso twice to make sure.

Comment: It looks like a nightmare. There must be a reasonable explanation. Did you try to disable UEFI and revert to legacy boot options in BIOS?

Comment: It might be a bug in LiveISO, maybe one of its drvivers is not compatible with your hardware. Try 13.04 liveISO

Comment: Here is a bug report similar to your error message https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/246834

Comment: please note that LiveISO must be the same architecture as you installed, otherwise you can't chroot into your system

Comment: Yeah. it's a nightmare. I am downloading the 13.10 version right now. Hopefully this will work.

Comment: Thank's a lot, kenn. The 13.10 version works. 
I had no important data on the laptop (It is only 2 weeks old), so I just installed 13.10 over the 14.04 (I got pretty sick at it, since this bothered me the whole day).

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you reinstalled your system. It's just  beginning, you must get ready for harder issues. Please calm down and be patient when problem arises